# filling multidimensional array with nested for loops

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, control-flow

I have four arrays, each with 3 (but can be more) elements. I am trying to fill a 4 x aa.length*bb.length*cc.length*dd.length array with all possible combinations of each element. I am trying to do this with nested for loops, but my logic is faulty. I am not sure what the most efficient way to do this would be.
this is what my caffeine starved brain has come up with so far.

```
String[] AA={DDDD, HHHH, ZZZZ};
String[] BB={DDDD, HHHH, ZZZZ};
String[] CC={DDDD, HHHH, ZZZZ};
String[] DD={DDDD, HHHH, ZZZZ};


String[][] 2Darray = new String[4][AA.length*BB.length*CC.length*DD.length];

for (int i = 0; i <AA.length; i++){

  for (int j = 0; j < BB.length; j++){

    for (int k = 0; k < CC.length; k++){

      for (int L = 0; L < DD.length; L++){

        2Darray[3][i+j+k+L] = DD[L]; 
        2Darray[2][i+j+k] = CC[k];
        2Darray[1][i+j] = BB[j];
        2Darray[0][i] = AA[i];

      }
    }
  }
}
```

the printed output of this looks like:

```
DDDD DDDD DDDD DDDD
HHHH DDDD DDDD DDDD
ZZZZ DDDD DDDD DDDD
null HHHH DDDD DDDD
null ZZZZ DDDD DDDD
null null HHHH DDDD
null null ZZZZ DDDD
null null null HHHH
null null null ZZZZ
null null null null
null null null null
null null null null
...etc
```

What is a better way to approach this?

Comment: woops, sorry new to this site.

I am trying to iterate column [3] first, then column [2] and so on. so column [0] will have something like 27 DDDD, 27 HHHH, and then 27 ZZZZ.

Comment: Do you want null to be present too as a part of your output?

Comment: No, Im trying to fill the whole 4x81 array with combinations of the other arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    String[] AA = {"DDDD", "HHHH", "ZZZZ"};
    String[] BB = {"DDDD", "HHHH", "ZZZZ"};
    String[] CC = {"DDDD", "HHHH", "ZZZZ"};
    String[] DD = {"DDDD", "HHHH", "ZZZZ"};


    String[][] result = new String[4][AA.length * BB.length * CC.length * DD.length];

    int row = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < AA.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < BB.length; j++) {

            for (int k = 0; k < CC.length; k++) {

                for (int L = 0; L < DD.length; L++) {

                    result[3][row] = DD[L];
                    result[2][row] = CC[k];
                    result[1][row] = BB[j];
                    result[0][row] = AA[i];
                    System.out.println(result[0][row] + " " +result[1][row] + " " +result[2][row] + " " +result[3][row]);
                    row++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and output

```
DDDD DDDD DDDD DDDD
DDDD DDDD DDDD HHHH
DDDD DDDD DDDD ZZZZ
DDDD DDDD HHHH DDDD
DDDD DDDD HHHH HHHH
DDDD DDDD HHHH ZZZZ
DDDD DDDD ZZZZ DDDD
...
```

Comment: I feel dumb for adding all of my iterators now. Thanks, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] AA={"1", "2", "3"};
        String[] BB={"4", "5", "6"};
        String[] CC={"7", "8", "9"};
        String[] DD={"10", "11", "12"};


        String[][] combinations = new String[AA.length*BB.length*CC.length*DD.length][4];

        // STORING INTO 2-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY
        int currentRow = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <AA.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < BB.length; j++){
                for (int k = 0; k < CC.length; k++){
                    for (int l = 0; l < DD.length; l++){
                        combinations[currentRow][0] = AA[i];
                        combinations[currentRow][1] = BB[j];
                        combinations[currentRow][2] = CC[k];
                        combinations[currentRow][3] = DD[l];
                        currentRow++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // PRINTING THE 2-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY

                for (int i = 0; i < AA.length*BB.length*CC.length*DD.length; i++){
                    System.out.println();
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                        System.out.print(combinations[i][j]+ " ");
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I beleive this is what you're trying to do. Remember, multidimensional array elements are just arrays (initialized to null). Also, you got the order of the dimensions backwards.

Edit: You also have to change 2Darray to something else because identifiers can't start with a digit. (In this case I changed it to x2Darray).

```
public class multidim{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] AA={"DDDD", "HHHH", "ZZZZ"};
        String[] BB={"DDDD", "HHHH", "ZZZZ"};
        String[] CC={"DDDD", "HHHH", "ZZZZ"};
        String[] DD={"DDDD", "HHHH", "ZZZZ"};

        String[][] x2Darray = new String[AA.length*BB.length*CC.length*DD.length][4];

        for (int i = 0; i <AA.length; i++){
          for (int j = 0; j < BB.length; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < CC.length; k++){
              for (int L = 0; L < DD.length; L++){
                String[] temp = {AA[i], BB[j], CC[k], DD[L]};
                x2Darray[((i*BB.length + j)*CC.length + k)*DD.length + L] = temp;
              }
            }
          }
        }

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for(String[] row: x2Darray){
            for(String x: row){ s.append(x); s.append(' '); }
            s.append("\n");             
        }

        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: 2darray[((i*BB.length + j)*CC.length + k)*DD.length + L] = temp;

2 things:
(1) Name used here '2darray' conflicts with the name used while declaration which is '2Darray'.

(2) If it is 2-dimensional array, then following statement is wrong:

2darray[((i*BB.length + j)*CC.length + k)*DD.length + L] = temp;

Comment: Wow, thanks antimony. It worked. though does it make a difference how I order the dimensions? I was thinking of them in terms of X and Y, and it made sense in my mind to order them as such.

Not sure why someone would downvote the answer that was exactly what the asker was looking for.

Comment: @user1607667...Can you please explain me how can there be 4*81 combinations? Is the order important too?

Comment: there would be 81 rows and 4 columns. not 4*81 combinations.

Comment: @Vikram how is the second statement wrong? Anyway, it seems silly to downvote over a typo, assuming that's what happened.

Comment: @Antimony...Friend, the reasons I downvoted have been mentioned in the comment. I assumed it wasn't a typo.

Comment: @Antimony, Even after reading my comment, just check your edit. You haven't taken care of my second point, i.e.,  (2) If it is 2-dimensional array, then following statement is wrong: 2darray[((i*BB.length + j)*CC.length + k)*DD.length + L] = temp;)

    It's not good to call my downvote as 'Silly', when even after reading my comment, you can't correct your silly mistakes!

Comment: @Vik That's because there's nothing wrong with it. After changing 2darray to a valid identifier, everything compiles and produces the expected output. I can put up the code for a complete class if you want to try it yourself.